# Returning default data not updated data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, foreach

I am trying to iterate over an array of objects which I then need to process another array of items that I need to query the database for and process the data to push into an array while updating a value in the array.

The below code does what I want in the sense of the order, the lookups, data processing etc however it does not allow me to return the updated `seriesData` to the API endpoint caller.

```
// Setup process
let seriesData = [];
const seriesDataTemplate = {
    x: "",
    y: 0,
    goals: [
        {
            name: "",
            value: 0,
                strokeHeight: 5,
            strokeColor: "#775DD0",
        }
    ]
};

// Some code not included that populates seriesData with seriesDataTemplate as the base for the object with x, y, goals.name and goals.value updated

// Area with the problem
itemIds.forEach(async itemId => {
    subArr.forEach(async sI => {
        const category = sI.category.toUpperCase().replace(/ /g, "_");
        const t = await getT(sI, category);
        sI.t = t;
        const total = t.reduce((acc, ta) => {
            return acc + ta.amount;
        }, 0);
        await updateSeriesData(sI, total);
    });
});

// Supporter function
async function updateSeriesData(sI, total) {
    let foundIndex = seriesData.findIndex(obj => obj.x === sI.category);
    seriesData[foundIndex].y = total;
}
```

This all runs inside an express.js route that is async and right after the end of this code I return `seriesData` to the user which only contains the template code

Comment: probbly has to do something with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: @cmgchess Amazing thank you! I converted each forEach loop to a for loop and it resolved my issue.

Comment: awesome. you cna write an answer if u want